# Circular permutation with restrictions

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How many ways can 12 children occupy the six banks of two
places on a ferris wheel if the order of two children sitting in one
bank is not relevant?

I know the answer when the order of children in a bank is relevant $\left (\frac {12!}{6} \right)$. What are the implications of the order not being more relevant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the youngest child get on the ferris wheel first in whatever cabin is at the ground at the time.  It doesn't matter which cabin it was, we don't care.

Pick another child to board the ferris wheel with them.  There are $11$ choices.

Rotate the ferris wheel so the next cabin can be boarded.  Pick two more children to board simultaneously.

Repeat this step until all children have boarded.

$$\dfrac{11!}{(2)^5}$$

Comment: I understood the explanation of the answer, but I couldn't get from it to $\frac {11!} {2^5} $. Can you detail the connection between the explanation and the answer?

Comment: would it help if I wrote it instead as $11\times \binom{10}{2}\times \binom{8}{2}\times \binom{6}{2}\times \binom{4}{2}\times \binom{2}{2}$?  You should be able to show these are equivalent.

Comment: The whole point is that while with circular permutations we "can't remember which way is north/south or up/down" but we *can* unambiguously know which direction the "smallest" element is in and can orient ourselves according to that.